# R, simulating effects of treatments including the effects of interaction between treatments

Tags: r, simulation

Think about an experiment with mice. We split the mice into 2 groups and we give to these groups different dose of cafein. We might also split each group receiving a given dose of cafein into 2 groups for which we give different dose of testosteron. We would have a so-called 2x2 design. The following matrix represents a 2x2x2 design.

```
> groups
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]    [,6]
    [1,]    1    1    1    1    2 -0.811962000
    [2,]    2    2    1    1    9  1.142115906
    [3,]    3    1    2    1    3 -0.999317454
    [4,]    4    2    2    1    7 -1.984324334
    [5,]    5    1    1    2   10  1.816095153
    [6,]    6    2    1    2    1  1.567284537
    [7,]    7    1    2    2    6  0.009253221
    [8,]    8    2    2    2    5 -1.764737015
```

Rows: individuals

column 1 : just an ID, don't pay much attention to it !

column 2 : groups for the first factor (cafein)

column 3 : groups for the second factor (testosteron)

column 3 : groups for the third factor (food quantity)

column 5 : just an ID, don't pay much attention to it !

column 6 : trait value (it could the difference to the mean weight of these mice after experiment)

In this particular matrix, we have 1 individual per group. Of course the design vary and the number of individuals per group also vary. We might have a 2x3x5 design (3 factors, 2,3 and 5 groups within the 1st, 2nd and 3rd factors) with 12 inds per group.

---

**My aim : Simulate some effects of these treatments.**

There are basically two types of effects:

**effect of on treatment (factors.effect object)**

and

**effect of interactions between treatments (interactions.effects object)**.

I have two objects:

```
> factors.effect
[1] 1 2 3

> interactions.effect
[[1]]
[1] 1 3
[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Those objects are "half-randomly" created.

I already solved how to apply the **factors.effect**. Here is the code I'm using.

```
                    for (factor.effect in factors.effect){
                        for (group.effect in unique(groups[,factor.effect+1])[-1]){
                            groups[which(groups[,factor.effect+1]==group.effect),ncol(groups)] = groups[which(groups[,factor.effect+1]==group.effect),ncol(groups)] + seq(from=0,to=treatment.factors.inloop,length.out=length(unique(groups[,factor.effect+1])))[group.effect]
                        }
                    }
```

treatment.factor.inloop contains a single integer which represents the maximum possible effect of a treatment. The code allows to give increasing effect as the group number increase.

**My question is: How can I compute a similar thing for interactions.effect ?**

So if we take interactions.effect [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln6E0.png)] (which is c(1,3)), the code should increase the trait value if factor1 and factor3 are high. But if any of these factors is equal to 1 (group 1), no effect should be added. I think it is not as simple as just taking the mean of the two factors. It is important this interaction effect is gradual as the factors.effect is.

If I then plot my data I should end up with something like that (apologize if it's not a beautiful plot !) :
[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: This may sound pedantic, but first you need to define "similar." Write yourself a flow chart or some equations which define what you want to do with interactions.  Then we can help convert into R-code.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It does not sound pedantic at all. Indeed, the R-code might be a problem to me but understanding what values I should increase in order to simulate an interaction is also a problem. I added some comments just after the "My Question is: ..." Thanks for your help !